# How do I specify more than one type to decode in the enum CodingKeys when using Codable?

Tags: swift, codable

I have a `struct` type which lists different types which must be decoded from JSON and I cannot find any information on how to specify more than one type in my `enum` called `CodingKeys`. In the innermost dictionary sometimes one key:value pair will be `[String:String]` and another key:value pair will be `[String:Int]`

I have tried specifying just `String` and `CodingKey` as in the code snippet below but Xcode reports 2 error messages.

```
struct JSONSiteData : Codable {
    let destinationAddresses : [String]
    let originAddresses : [String]
    let rows : [    [String : [[String:[[String: [String:Any]]]]]]      ]
    let status : String
}

enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
    case destinationAddresses = "destination_addresses"
    case originAddresses = "origin_addresses"
    case rows
    case status
}
```

I get the following error messages from Xcode;

```
Type 'JSONSiteData' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'
Type 'JSONSiteData' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'
```

Here is my JSON;

```
{
    "destination_addresses": [
        "1 Dunwell Ln, Bolam, Darlington DL2 2UW, UK",
        "Unnamed Road, Newton Aycliffe DL5 6QZ, UK",
        "Preston Manor Farm, Preston le Skerne, Newton Aycliffe DL5 6JH, United Kingdom",
        "6 Middridge Farms, Middridge, Newton Aycliffe DL5 7JQ, UK",
        "1 The Gardens, Hunwick, Crook DL15 0XW, UK"
    ],
    "origin_addresses": [
        "42 Drovers Way, Dunstable LU6 1AW, UK"
    ],
    "rows": [
        {
            "elements": [
                {
                    "distance": {
                        "text": "220 mi",
                        "value": 353731
                    },
                    "duration": {
                        "text": "3 hours 45 mins",
                        "value": 13475
                    },
                    "status": "OK"
                },
                {
                    "distance": {
                        "text": "222 mi",
                        "value": 356696
                    },
                    "duration": {
                        "text": "3 hours 45 mins",
                        "value": 13471
                    },
                    "status": "OK"
                },
                {
                    "distance": {
                        "text": "222 mi",
                        "value": 358053
                    },
                    "duration": {
                        "text": "3 hours 46 mins",
                        "value": 13545
                    },
                    "status": "OK"
                },
                {
                    "distance": {
                        "text": "225 mi",
                        "value": 361421
                    },
                    "duration": {
                        "text": "3 hours 49 mins",
                        "value": 13768
                    },
                    "status": "OK"
                },
                {
                    "distance": {
                        "text": "229 mi",
                        "value": 369280
                    },
                    "duration": {
                        "text": "3 hours 57 mins",
                        "value": 14238
                    },
                    "status": "OK"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"
}
```

Comment: You cannot decode `Any`. All value types must conform to `Decodable`

Comment: @vadian So how do I decode a String and Int without using Any?

Comment: @sjlearmonth edit your question and add your json string

Comment: This is not JSON. The collection type output doesn't help because `Int` and `String` are displayed similarly.

Comment: @vadian I have added the JSON output from Postman.

Comment: @LeoDabus I have added the JSON output from Postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this,

```
// To parse the JSON, add this file to your project and do:
//
//   let jsonSiteData = try? newJSONDecoder().decode(JSONSiteData.self, from: jsonData)

import Foundation

struct JSONSiteData: Codable {
    let destinationAddresses, originAddresses: [String]
    let rows: [Row]
    let status: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case destinationAddresses = "destination_addresses"
        case originAddresses = "origin_addresses"
        case rows, status
    }
}

struct Row: Codable {
    let elements: [Element]
}

struct Element: Codable {
    let distance, duration: Distance
    let status: String
}

struct Distance: Codable {
    let text: String
    let value: Int
}
```

Refer this link to generate models from JSON Strings.
https://app.quicktype.io/

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of `Codable` there are no different types.

Decode these structs

```
struct JSONSiteData : Decodable {
    let destinationAddresses : [String]
    let originAddresses : [String]
    let rows : [Row]
    let status : String
}

struct Row : Decodable {
    let elements : [Element]
}

struct Element : Decodable {
    let distance : Item
    let duration : Item
    let status : String
}

struct Item : Decodable {
    let text : String
    let value : Int
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try that.